# R Iterators / Loops ( finding momentum / direction )

Tags: r, loops, iterator

Look at the following data frame

`1   1   3
 2   1   6
 3   1   7
 2   1   6
 3   1   7 
 4   1   8
 5   1   13
 6   0   10
 5   1   13
 4   1   12
 5   1   13
 6   1   14
 7   NA NA
 8   0   16
 7   NA NA
 6   NA NA`

On the left column i have a small sample.

On the center column i have a testing value: `if the number on the left eventually rises by a value of 2 before dropping by a value of 2, the binary value is "1", if the number declines first by 2 before rising 2, the binary is "0"`

On the third column, i want the position where the criteria was met

2 rises to 4 ... the dummy is "1"... the last column says that "4" was on position 6

6 declines to 4 before reaching 8, so the dummy is "0". The last column says that specific "4" was on position 10

**Edit:**

Thank you Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this may work for you.

```
x <- data.frame(V1 = c(1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 5, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 7, 6))


for(i in 1:nrow(x)){
  for(j in i:nrow(x)){
    if(x[j,1] - x[i,1] == 2){
      x[i,2] <- 1
      x[i,3] <- j
      break()
    } else if(x[j,1] - x[i,1] == -2){
      x[i,2] <- 0
      x[i,3] <- j
      break()
    } else{
      x[i,2] <- NA
      x[i,3] <- NA
    }
  }
}
```